# Swift force dark/light mode inside an app

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I want user to press a button and force change the dark/light mode inside an app,
code works ,but need to press **twice** the button to get it work,
weird... can anyone take a look? thanks!

```
func darkOrLight() {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        } else {
            window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger. What happens exactly on the first button press? Then what happens on the second?

Comment: Also note that `keyWindow` is deprecated in iOS 13.

Answer (score 5):

func darkOrlightMode(){

```
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

    if UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .dark {

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light

    }
    else {

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark

    }
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes

Answer (score 0):

problem solved,
don't use overrideUserInterFaceStyle to check current theme mode,

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
else {
    window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what you want. This will set the window's style to be the opposite of the device's style. This isn't going to toggle the current window override.

Comment: @rmaddy  now I press the button will change between dark/light mode, but yes as you said it did not override the default style, next time open the app will still go with device's style. any suggestions for maintain the change? :)

Answer (score 0):

This code presumes that the only two values are `dark` and `light`. But the initial [`UIUserInterfaceStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiuserinterfacestyle) value is [`unspecified`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiuserinterfacestyle/unspecified), in which case it uses the current system setting.

Rather than having “dark” vs “light” in your app, consider giving them three choices, “dark”, “light”, and “system default”.